# Async is not working when using with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I am listening to a firebase database and fetching object from it. first time async tag is working fine.Next time onwards it is giving error as cant read property students of null ( image 1)

Code:
[image: code]

Console showing error:

[image: error]

Comment: 1) Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. 2) Also note that none of the code in your question seems to interact with a database It'll be hard to help with that unless we see the relevant code.

Comment: try this on each of them: `(author$ | async)?.name`.